# What does the new operator return?

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am a beginner and this question always confuses me. My academic book says that the `new` operator returns an address. But in many tutorials, I found that `new` returns a pointer pointing to a particular address. Take this:

```
  char *name = new char[x];
```

What value is assigned to `name` here, an address that has been dynamically allocated or a pointer that points to dynamically allocated `char`?

Comment: Note that "address" and "pointer" mean the same thing to the C and C++ languages, and have no relationship to the hardware idea of the address of a memory location beyond the mere fact that that's how the compiler usually implements them.

Comment: A pointer is a variable that is capable of storing an address. The address returned by `new` is stored in the pointer. That's why we call them *pointers* because they point to an address.

Answer (score 5):

Pointer is a variable containing an address of another variable. So both statements are roughly the same. The pointer is returned which contains an address.

When you say that pointer points to something, it means that it contains its address.

Answer (score 1):

Operator new returns a **pointer** to a beginning of an array.

Pointer is the address of some cell in memory.

that's why we can say: Operator new returns a **address** to a beginning of an array.

---

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

In short: The new operator returns the unique address of the allocated object. When you allocate an array of objects the address of the first object is returned.

```
char *name = new char[x];
// name is a char pointer that contains the address to the first char from your char array
```

`name[0]` accesses the first element of the array.
`name[1]` accesses the second element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The result of an array-form new expression (like `new char[x]`) is a pointer (in this case of type `char *`).   When using the array form of operator `new`, as you are, the value of that pointer is the address of the first element of the dynamically allocated array.   When using the non-array form (as in `new char`) a single object is allocated, and the pointer has a value equal to the address of that object.

The value of the variable `name` assigned by the statement `char *name = new char[x]` is the value of the pointer given by the expression `new char [x]`.

If an error occurs during the allocation, then operator new throws an exception rather than returning a value, and the variable `name` never receives a value.   [This can be changed by using alternative forms of operator new that return `NULL` on error, and do not throw, but you have not done that].

Answer (score 0):

The value of an array-new expression `new T[N]` is the address of the first element of a dynamically allocated array of size `N` of `T`. The type of this value is `T *`, i.e. the pointer type of such an address.

The array object itself is not generally addressable, and you cannot generally name the complete object (in fact, you cannot even say its *type*). You can only name each of its element subobjects, and you can only destroy and deallocate the array object via the address of its first element.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
new char[x]
```

allocates an array of `char` objects, and returns a pointer (of type `char*`) to the object at index zero.

If you wanted to dynamically allocate a pointer, you would use

```
new char*
```

which dynamically allocates an object of type `char*`, and returns to a pointer (of type `char**`) to it.