# What does int** outer = new int*[n] in this code mean?

Tags: c++

I just started learning programming and c++. I can't seem to wrap my head around pointers and variable sized array. I didn't know how to solve this problem on hackerrank so I tried to look and understand the solution in the editorial.

So I think the code is supposed to take input of n number of arrays, q numbers of queries, the size of and values in each arrays, and find/query xth data in yth array (for example if the input is 0 1, then we need to find the value of array[0][1]).

Suppose that the input is:

2 2

3 1 5 4

5 1 2 8 9 3

0 1

1 3

The output should be:

5

9

2 arrays so there are :

array[0][] with the size 3 and values of {1, 5, 4}

array[1][] with the size of 5 and values of {1, 2, 8, 9, 3}

2 queries so we need to look for  the values in:

array[0][1] which is 5

array[1][3] which is 9

But what I don't understand is how do I make arrays of arrays, and why do I have to use pointers and how do I do that? The solution also includes int** which I think means pointer to pointer. What does that even mean??? And how do I use new int? Why does the new int is also a pointer (new int*[n])??

```
int main() {
    int n;
    int q;
    cin >> n >> q;
    
    int** outer = new int*[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int k;
        cin >> k;
        
        outer[i] = new int[k];

        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            cin >> outer[i][j];
        }
    }

    
    while(q-- > 0) {
        int outer_index;
        int inner_index;
        cin >> outer_index >> inner_index;

        cout << outer[outer_index][inner_index] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am clueless. pls help.

Comment: `new` is an advanced tool, depsite how some bad tutorials make it look like. You will rarely use it in your job. Most of the time you'll use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` as a 2D array, or even better just a 1D `std::vector<int>` of size `m*n`. Of course you still need to understand how pointers and `new` work, your C++ book will explain that. But you don't need to jump to them to solve a simple exercise.

Comment: @jwryd - What you *might* learn from this is that hackerrank is a terrible place to learn C++ (or programming in general). Despite some popular culture memes, good software developers don't consider themselves hackers. We are way above that level! :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the new operator returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453095/what-does-the-new-operator-returns)

Comment: It means the code is still using "C" style memory management.  Where are you learning C++ from? Your source material seems at least 12 years out of date (possibly longer)

Comment: This is what current C++ material should teach you to use  : https://onlinegdb.com/hVS75HARMQ

Answer (score 1):

You know that `int* a;` defines the variable `a` as a pointer to an `int`, right? It's the same with more asterisks, it's add more pointers. So `int** a;` defines `a` as a pointer to a pointer to an `int`.

And `new int*[n]` creates an array of `n` elements, where each element is an `int*`. Since `new` returns a pointer to what's created, a pointer to `int*` must then be `int**`.

---

If we take the time to "draw" what's happening, then `outer = new int*[n]` would create something like this:

```
+--------------+
|   outer[0]   | --> ?
+--------------+
|   outer[1]   | --> ?
+--------------+
|      ...     |
+--------------+
| outer[n - 1] | --> ?
+--------------+
```

So you have an array of pointers. The elements in this array are not initialized, they don't point anywhere valid. Which is why the arrows are pointing to the question mark `?`.

Then inside the loop you have the statement

```
outer[i] = new int[k];
```

It allocates an array of `int` elements.

After the loop the drawing then becomes something like this instead:

```
+--------------+     +-------------+-------------+-----+-----------------+
|   outer[0]   | --> | outer[0][0] | outer[0][1] | ... | outer[0][k - 1] |
+--------------+     +-------------+-------------+-----+-----------------+
|   outer[1]   | --> | outer[1][0] | outer[1][1] | ... | outer[1][k - 1] |
+--------------+     +-------------+-------------+-----+-----------------+
|      ...     |
+--------------+     +-----------------+-----------------+-----+---------------------+
| outer[n - 1] | --> | outer[n - 1][0] | outer[n - 1][1] | ... | outer[n - 1][k - 1] |
+--------------+     +-----------------+-----------------+-----+---------------------+
```

I hope this helps you understand what's going on.